# How to correctly specify relative paths when going up/down several levels

Tags: r, filepath, relative-path

I have the following folder structure:

```
04  
 |--folder 1  
07  
 |--folder 2  
   |--folder 3  
     |-- ABC.rproj
```

So I have an R project two levels down in the 07 folder.

I now want to load a file from folder 1 in 04, but I always get an error and I don't understand why. I'm using relative paths in many, many projects and it works just fine, just not here, so my guess is it is because of teh fact that the rproj and hence the working directory is two levels down?

Assume there's an Excel file in folder 1 called "test.xlsx" then I would usually read that in with:

```
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("../../04/folder 1/test.xlsx")
```

But it doesn't work.

Where am I going wrong?

The weird thing is, checking the file existence works, i.e. `list.files("../../04/folder 1/", pattern = ".xslx")` returns `[1] test.xlsx`

Edit: it works until a certain path depth, i.e. if I put the file one level up it reads it in.

Doesn't work:

```
df <- read_excel("../../04/A/B/C/D/E/F/test.xlsx")
```

Does work:

```
df <- read_excel("../../04/A/B/C/D/E/test.xlsx")
```

Comment: `read_excel` uses `normalizePath`. What is the result of `file.exists(normalizePath('../../04/folder 1/test.xlsx'))`?

Comment: It gives a warning message that the file name or the extension is too long? And returns FALSE for the file.exists.

Comment: If I do the same with the folder structure A/B/C/D/E, then it works and returns TRUE.

Comment: So is my file path too long?

Comment: Possibly. You might need if you're under Windows to [make Windows accept long file paths](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/)

Comment: OK, unfortunately not an option on our WIndows Server structure says IT. Any other way to make it work (other than the obviously cutting of the heavily nested folder structure)?

Comment: Perhaps try `file.copy` to `tmpdir <- tempdir()`, and then `read_excel` from `tmpdir`. Could work as `list.files` also seems to work.